# Scheduling/Queueing a job within another job with redis queue

Tags: python, redis, rq

`Tasker` class setups the initial job when instantiated. Basically what I want is put a job in the 'main_queue', decide if job is running or if there is already same job that is queued in the 'process_queue', return from the the current 'main_queue' job. Else queue a job in the 'process_queue'. When that process queue finishes, put a job in the 'main_queue'.

however, the 'process_queue' has the same job with id for that duration, despite it should have been finished looking at the outputs. So a new job is never put in to process. Is there a deadlock happening that I am unable to see?

main_queue worker

```
$ rq worker main_queue --with-scheduler
22:44:19 Worker rq:worker:7fe23a24ae404135a10e301f7509eb7e: started, version 1.9.0
22:44:19 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:7fe23a24ae404135a10e301f7509eb7e
22:44:19 *** Listening on main_queue...
22:44:19 Trying to acquire locks for main_queue
22:44:19 Scheduler for main_queue started with PID 3747
22:44:19 Cleaning registries for queue: main_queue
22:44:33 main_queue: tasks.redis_test_job() (e90e0dff-bbcc-48ab-afed-6d1ba8b020a8)
None
Job is enqueued to process_queue!
22:44:33 main_queue: Job OK (e90e0dff-bbcc-48ab-afed-6d1ba8b020a8)
22:44:33 Result is kept for 500 seconds
22:44:47 main_queue: tasks.redis_test_job() (1a7f91d0-73f4-466e-92f4-9f918a9dd1e9)
<Job test_job: tasks.print_job()>
!!Scheduler added job to main but same job is already queued in process_queue!!
22:44:47 main_queue: Job OK (1a7f91d0-73f4-466e-92f4-9f918a9dd1e9)
22:44:47 Result is kept for 500 seconds
```

process_queue worker

```
$ rq worker process_queue
22:44:24 Worker rq:worker:d70daf20ff324c18bc17f0ea9576df52: started, version 1.9.0
22:44:24 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:d70daf20ff324c18bc17f0ea9576df52
22:44:24 *** Listening on process_queue...
22:44:24 Cleaning registries for queue: process_queue
22:44:33 process_queue: tasks.print_job() (test_job)
The process job executed.
22:44:42 process_queue: Job OK (test_job)
22:44:42 Result is kept for 500 seconds
```

tasker.py

```
class Tasker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasker_conn = RedisClient().conn
        self.process_queue = Queue(name='process_queue', connection=Redis(), 
                                   default_timeout=-1)
        self.main_queue = Queue(name='main_queue', connection=Redis(),
                                    default_timeout=-1)
        self.__setup_tasks()
    def __setup_tasks(self):
        self.main_queue.enqueue_in(timedelta(seconds=3), tasks.redis_test_job)
```

tasks.py

```
import tasks
def redis_test_job():
    q = Queue('process_queue', connection=Redis(), default_timeout=-1)
    queued = q.fetch_job('test_job')
    print(queued)
    if queued:
        print("!!Scheduler added job to main but same job is already queued in process_queue!!")
        return False
    else:
        q.enqueue(tasks.print_job, job_id='test_job')
        print("Job is enqueued to process_queue!")
    return True

def print_job():
    sleep(8)
    print("The process job executed.")
    q = Queue('main_queue', connection=Redis(), default_timeout=-1)
    q.enqueue_in(timedelta(seconds=5), tasks.redis_test_job)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/jobs/#time-to-live-for-job-in-queue), enqueued jobs have a `result_ttl` that defaults to [500 seconds](https://python-rq.org/docs/jobs/#rqs-job-object) if you don't define it.

If you want to change it to e.g. make the job and result live for only 1 second, enqueue your job like this:

```
 q.enqueue(tasks.print_job, job_id='test_job', result_ttl=1)
```

Comment: I figured this about a minute after writing the question. I just assumed for some reason the job will leave the queue as soon as the job finishes executing.